# Prevent an object from being serialized with Knockout.js toJS/toJSON

Tags: knockout.js

I am using [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) and to avoid any issues with PCI compliance the credit card data entered on my forms should never be transmitted from browser to server. Users shall enter credit-card data into forms with Knockout.js.

Mostly as a matter of interest (mostly so I understand better how knockout.js works), I would like to come up with a way to prevent serialization of credit-card data by having an explicit error occur whenever serialization of the data is attempted in the usual knockout.js way (ie `ko.toJS` or `ko.toJSON` or `ko.mapping.*` equivalents).

To achieve this I thought I could do something clever, like this (in CoffeeScript):

```
class NeverSerialize
  datums = ko.observable()
  blocker = ko.computed(
    read: () -> throw new Error("You shall not pass!")
    deferEvaluation: true
  )
```

and when `ko.toJS/toJSON` or equivalent is called it would execute `blocker()` and that would call the `read` function and be the end of it.

This idea almost works - as you can see from [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/xYkWA/). Unfortunately it only executes `read()` the first time, but it is never called after. I gather this is because there are no observables that `read` depends upon, so knockout presumes that the value of the computed will not have changed.

So I guess I am curious about two things:

1. Is this conceptually a sensible way to go about preventing an observable from being serialized with `ko.toJS/toJSON`? (or, generically, having a function execute whenever a `read` is called on a computed observable)
2. How would one go about having a computed variable's `read` function called every time it is accessed (i.e. avoid caching it)?

I am just curious about how one might go about this sort of thing with Knockout.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than doing all that, just define a `toJSON` function which will return an object that contains the properties you want serialized.  i.e., create a copy of your view model and remove the properties from the copy you don't want serialized.

```
function ViewModel(model) {
    this.name = ko.observable(model.name);
    this.password = ko.observable(model.password);

    this.toJSON = function () {
        var copy = ko.toJS(this);
        delete copy.password;
        return copy;
    }
}
```

---

If you really wanted to do this, I suppose you could do this.  The `ko.toJS` function goes through all the properties of an object and maps the value to a new object.  So if it is not an observable, it will simply copy it, otherwise it will invoke (read) it.  You need to trick knockout into unconditionally invoke your observable so you may always throw an error upon reading it.

You can write up a new observable hierarchy that would be a non-caching version, but that's a lot of stuff you probably don't need.  You just need to create an observable which throws errors ultimately.  So what you can do is create a function that will just throw an error and trick knockout into thinking it is an observable.  Fortunately, knockout checks this by seeing it has an observable as a prototype through a special property.

```
ko.errorObservable = function (thrower) {
    function errorObservable() {
        if (typeof thrower === 'function') {
            thrower();
        }
    }
    // trick knockout into thinking this is an observable so it will be invoked
    errorObservable[ko.observable.protoProperty] = ko.observable;
    return errorObservable;
};
```

Then it's just a matter of adding the observable to your view model and you're set.

```
function ViewModel(model) {
    this.name = ko.observable(model.name);
    this.password = ko.observable(model.password);
    this._neverSerialize = ko.errorObservable(function () {
        throw new Error("Serialization of this model is prohibited.");
    });
}
```

Of course, this relies on undocumented behavior.  The way knockout determines these things may change in the future.  Use at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. That's certainly the idea, and this works for simple cases where a password property is to be excluded. It's not quite what I'm looking for because 1.) I would like something that could be put into a generic library of reusable models, 2.) this only omits a single observable and I would like an explicit error (not silent omission) and the entire ViewModel refusing to serialize, and 3.) I do not think this would not work with `ko{mapping}.toJS/toJSON`. Thanks for contributing this to the discussion, though!

Comment: Oh so you wanted that error, even on the `toJS` function. I think that's doable, not sure if it's advisable however.

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternative I found by accident after first reading this post:

If you set the `enumerable` option of the property to `false` it will not be serialized.

For instance when creating an object with `Object.create()`:

```
const obj = Object.create(objProto, {
        name: { value: name, enumerable: true },
        items: { value: items, enumerable: false }
    });
```

In this case `items` will not show up in the serialized string from `ko.toJSON()`

Comment: Thanks @David - good catch.  Another alternative that'll work is to use a `Symbol` for the property name (as they are, by default, not enumerable).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article on `knockmeout`

It's basically the same method as Jeff's answer, but with just more details.

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html